# CSS - how to change the style of 2 different siblings?

Tags: css

The issue is due to using a third party library. I cannot change the required styling.

How can I change the width's of **2 seperate child elements** which are part of the third party library?

In my HTML I can use the '3rd-party-outer-tag' tag. It has no styling parameter to overrule the default sizes of the child-1 'div' and child-2 'div'.

Using the developer tools, I see this code that has this structure:

```
<3rd-party-outer-tag>
  <other-tag>
     <div class="col-md-10" .... > 
        <...>
     <div class="col-md-2 pagination pull-right float-sm-right" .... > 
        <...>
  </other-tag>
</3rd-party-outer-tag>
```

The size of the second child is far too small, so I want to change that size:

```
<3rd-party-outer-tag>
  <other-tag>
     <div class="col-md-8" .... > 
        <...>
     <div class="col-md-4 pagination pull-right float-sm-right" .... > 
        <...>
  </other-tag>
</3rd-party-outer-tag>
```

My first try is just to overrule the child tags with only 1 'width'. Of course, this is not the ideal solution, but could work in an Angular environment:

```
::ng-deep 3rd-party-outer-tag > other-tag > div {
  width: 50.0%;
}
```

Do you have a better solution? The 'ng-deep' used for overruling the CSS of a child in an Angular environment. You may skip it.

Comment: Can't you change col-md-8 and col-md-4 to col-md-6?

Comment: That's ok. I am convinced that relying on inner tag or `class` is the only way to change it

Comment: @EmanuelSaramago as I understand these are styles provided by library so we can't access them

Comment: I can only access the outer tag, the rest is hidden in the library (that is not on github).

Comment: You should check the CSS applied to the "3rd-party-outer-tag" and children in the developer tools as well. The `::ng deep` approach in Angular only works if the css selectors contain attribute selectors like `[_ngcontent-c2]` or `[_nghost-c1]`.

Comment: `::ng-deep` will create CSS code without these so you can write global styles and address 3rd party components this way. To override the local component CSS you will still have to create a selector with higher priority than the existing ones.

Comment: Thanx. @ArthurNoetzel, Can you please elaborate a bit?